# Need to show alert message when clicking on a tabpane inside an ajax tab container

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tcMain" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="986px">
<asp:TabPanel ID="tp1" HeaderText="H1" runat="server">
</asp:TabPanel>
<asp:TabPanel ID="tp2" HeaderText="H2" runat="server">
 </asp:TabPanel>
 </asp:TabContainer>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tp2").click(function () {
        alert("Done");         
    });
});
```

In the above code when clicking on TabPanel "tp2", the alert message should appear

Comment: The title says ajax, but i don't see any ajax.

Comment: Is jQuery included on the page?

Comment: What your console says? Any errors? How looks the code generated by "<asp:TabPanel ID="tp2" HeaderText="H2" runat="server">
 </asp:TabPanel>"?

Comment: TabContainer is ajax control

Comment: Alexey, i wanna simple message when i click on TabPanel "tp2"

Comment: Reference jquery on your code `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: try to use ClientID for server control, 
$("#<%=txt1.ClientID%>")

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't add reference to jQuery (open your console(F12 in most browsers) and check if you see message like 'function $ is not defined'). Also you can do it by pure javascript:

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('tp2');
element.onclick = function(){
   alert('done');
}
</script>
```

Or simply add onClick="javascript: window.alert('done');" on the html tag needed event handler.

```
onClick="javascript: window.alert('test');"
```

Comment: Could you show me markup generated by "<asp:TabPanel ID="tp2" HeaderText="H2" runat="server"></asp:TabPanel>"? Also check if you have only one element with id="tp2".